# CS50 filter-more edges doesn't pass check50. What is wrong?

Tags: c, filter, cs50, edges

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define RED_COLOR 0
#define GREEN_COLOR 1
#define BLUE_COLOR 2
#define POS_X 0
#define POS_Y 1
```

```
int getEdge(int i, int j, int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int color_position, int position)
{
     int gx[3][3]={
        {-1, 0, 1},
        {-2, 0, 2},
        {-1, 0, 1}
    };

    int gy[3][3]={
        {-1, -2, 1},
        {0, 0, 0},
        {1, 2, 1}
    };

    int row_count = 0;
    int col_count = 0;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int row = i - 1; row <= (i + 1); row++)
    {
        col_count = 0;
        for (int column = j - 1; column <= (j + 1); column++)
        {

            if (row < 0 || row >= height || column < 0 || column >= width)
            {
                sum += 0;
            }
            if (color_position == RED_COLOR)
            {
                if (position == POS_X)
                    sum += image[row][column].rgbtRed * gx[row_count][col_count];
                else
                    sum += image[row][column].rgbtRed * gy[row_count][col_count];
             }
            else if (color_position == GREEN_COLOR)
            {
                if (position == POS_X)
                    sum += image[row][column].rgbtGreen * gx[row_count][col_count];
                else
                    sum += image[row][column].rgbtGreen * gy[row_count][col_count];
            }
            else
            {
                if (position == POS_X)
                    sum += image[row][column].rgbtBlue * gx[row_count][col_count];
                else
                    sum += image[row][column].rgbtBlue * gy[row_count][col_count];
            }
            col_count++;
        }
        row_count++;
    }
    return sum;
}

// Calculate sobel value for each channel (capping at 255)
int sobel (int Gx, int Gy)
{
    int n = sqrt(Gx^2 + Gy^2);
    n = fmin(255, n);
    return n;
}

// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    // copy image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = sobel(getEdge(i, j, height, width, copy, RED_COLOR, POS_X), getEdge(i, j, height, width, copy, RED_COLOR, POS_Y));
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sobel(getEdge(i, j, height, width, copy, GREEN_COLOR, POS_X), getEdge(i, j, height, width, copy, GREEN_COLOR, POS_Y));
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sobel(getEdge(i, j, height, width, copy, BLUE_COLOR, POS_X), getEdge(i, j, height, width, copy, BLUE_COLOR, POS_Y));
        }

    return;
}
```

After submit get results:

```
:( edges correctly filters middle pixel
Cause
expected "210 150 60\n", not "4 15 10\n"
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (0, 10, 25), (0, 10, 30), (40, 60, 80)
second row: (20, 30, 90), (30, 40, 100), (80, 70, 90)
third row: (20, 20, 40), (30, 10, 30), (50, 40, 10)
```

```
:( edges correctly filters pixel on edge
Cause
expected "213 228 255\n", not "19 20 15\n"
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (0, 10, 25), (0, 10, 30), (40, 60, 80)
second row: (20, 30, 90), (30, 40, 100), (80, 70, 90)
third row: (20, 20, 40), (30, 10, 30), (50, 40, 10)
```

```
:( edges correctly filters pixel in corner
Cause
expected "76 117 255\n", not "0 0 0\n"
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (0, 10, 25), (0, 10, 30), (40, 60, 80)
second row: (20, 30, 90), (30, 40, 100), (80, 70, 90)
third row: (20, 20, 40), (30, 10, 30), (50, 40, 10)
```

```
:( edges correctly filters 3x3 image
Cause
expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "0 17 0\n15 11 ..."
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (0, 10, 25), (0, 10, 30), (40, 60, 80)
second row: (20, 30, 90), (30, 40, 100), (80, 70, 90)
third row: (20, 20, 40), (30, 10, 30), (50, 40, 10)
```

Comment: What kind of debugging strategy have you used so far?

Comment: Is this supposed to be squaring...? `sqrt(Gx^2 + Gy^2)`. If so try `sqrt((double)Gx * Gx + (double)Gy * Gy)`

Comment: Hint: `^` is **XOR** not *to the power of*.

Comment: Aside: `fmin` should be `min`, the operands are `int`.

Comment: Thank You, I rewrote sqrt((double)Gx * Gx + (double)Gy * Gy), and instead of fmin uses if n > 255 n = 255 ... bus still check50 returns errors :( edges correctly filters middle pixel
Cause
expected "210 150 60\n", not "255 186 108\n"
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (0, 10, 25), (0, 10, 30), (40, 60, 80)
second row: (20, 30, 90), (30, 40, 100), (80, 70, 90)
third row: (20, 20, 40), (30, 10, 30), (50, 40, 10)

Comment: .... and, what debugging strategy have you used to find the problem?